# Разные картинки при разных разрешениях экрана Unity2d

Tags: c#, unity3d

подскажите как через скрипт(c#) узнать разрешение экрана, пример: хочу сделать чтоб на разрешениях 320x480 была картинка No1, на 400x800 была картинка No2 И так далее.
В скрипте должно быть:

1. Узнать разрешение телефона
2. И проверить если разрешение *x* то сделать No*.SetActive(true) если нет проветиь если разрешение *x* то сделать No*.SetActive(true) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> подскажите как через скрипт(c#) узнать разрешение экрана

Screen.width

Screen.height

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-width.html

> И проверить если разрешение x то сделать

if ( Screen.width == x && Screen.height == y)
{
    //Z action
}

Comment: Спасибо, все сработало

Comment: Просто отметь галочкой:)